The body textarea behaves very strangely in Edge
I've used Stack Overflow from Firefox and Chrome for many years, Chrome most recently. Due to some problems with my laptop and other annoying details I won't go into, I'm now forced to use Edge.  I'm finding that posting to Stack Overflow in Edge presents one very odd set of problems.  All the "single-line" text fields work fine, but when I click in the "Body" textarea, something really odd happens. It suddenly switches to a "full-window" view of the text area, with icons for font styles and other things, then a menu bar, and then the textarea.
When I start typing, I didn't see any characters appear, until I looked closely and realized that the characters I entered were appearing underneath the menu bar, and the menu bar is slightly transparent. The easiest hack to avoid this problem is to simply enter a newline as the first character. I can now see what I type.
However, when I'm done typing the body, it's not clear what I'm supposed to do at that point. There is no "Return to form" action anywhere. The only hack that works here is simply clicking "Back", which aborts the entire form, but since Stack Overflow caches all the form values, I just click "Ask Question" again, and it restores what I had entered in a "normal" view.  If I click in the Body area again, it jumps back to that weird mode.
Update:

This is what I get when I simply click in the Body area:

This is what I see after typing some characters in the Body area:

If you look closely, you can see several “x” characters are displayed underneath the somewhat transparent menu bar, with a red squiggle underneath them.
This is after entering a newline at the end of that line, and additional characters:


Is this about Stack Snippets?

No, just an ordinary SO posting, like this one. I had to go through the same steps to write this post.

I'm unable to reproduce in Edge. Can you please confirm you're not using a beta, dev, or canary version of Edge, and can you please provide a screenshot?

This is my version string: Version 125.0.2535.92 (Official build) (64-bit) . Note that this is managed by my organization. Before this week, I've only ever briefly used Edge, I normally use Chrome. I'll update the post with screenshots.

Actually, no, I cannot add screenshots, for reasons similar to the original problem. That mutant mode of the Body textarea won't let me paste screenshots.

Images are not uploaded for posts by pasting.  There is an icon on top edge of the edit window that allows one to upload an image file.  Have you seen the icon that looks like a  moon over two mountain peaks?  The hover text for it is "Image (Ctrl-G)".

This is something local on your device and/or network/ISP - if it was on SE side, we would be seeing many other users with this problem.

@hardmath "Images are not uploaded for posts by pasting." -- Ctrl+V with an image in the clipboard pops up the same thing (which says "Browse, drag & drop, or paste an image or link") with the image ready to be added (the "Add" button already active and thumbnail shown).
